# Fatal Exception: Main java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: java, android, fatal-error, lang

Here's my Logcat:

```
08-04 16:54:17.330: I/dalvikvm(13558): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 13...
08-04 16:54:17.370: D/AndroidRuntime(13558): Shutting down VM
08-04 16:54:17.370: W/dalvikvm(13558): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception(group=0x40a261f8)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.infiniviewer/com.infiniviewer.InfiniviewerActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infiniviewer.InfiniviewerActivity
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infiniviewer.InfiniviewerActivity
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1023)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
08-04 16:54:17.380: E/AndroidRuntime(13558):    ... 11 more
----------
08-04 16:54:19.790: I/Process(13558): Sending signal. PID: 13558 SIG: 9
```

Here is my Manifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.infiniviewer"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <!--  <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="com.wecoatessurveying_2.Application" android:debuggable="true">  -->


     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="13" />



    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />


       <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:debuggable="true" android:hardwareAccelerated="false"> 


           <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />


           <activity android:name=".InfiniviewerActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".LayersActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:hardwareAccelerated="true"/>
        <activity android:name=".CalibrateGPSActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"/>
        <activity android:name=".SelectSPCSActivitytSPCSActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"/>


    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: no starting/ending manifest tags or you just didnt paste them ?

Comment: maybe not, could you elaborate? I did not right this code, my developer did, we ran out of development funds, and had to let him go, so im having to continue as I can, it worked on his end, however when I load the complete source code into eclipse and try to run, I get the fatal error, so im not sure if I am missing something or not, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: by the way, the Manifest.XML file is an exact copy/paste from my eclipse, so what is shown above, is how I have it in eclipse...

Comment: update for ^^, I do have start/end manifest tags in my XML in eclipse, for some reason they didn't copy/paste sry.

Comment: @user2647631 Edited to add code markup so the xml does not get interpreted as html.

Answer (score 1):

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.infiniviewer.InfiniviewerActivity
```

Where is your InfiniviewerActivity? How did you build your project?

Comment: I simply imported the source code from a file my developer sent me, into eclipse, I did not build this project, my developer did, however we ran out of funds, and had to let him go, so im having to do what I can, as I can, and I am a beginner. it did work on his end, he simply loaded all the files into google docs, I downloaded and imported into eclipse.

Comment: this is a demo of the working app my developer made a few months ago, whos the app working on his end, however I get a FATAL when trying to run it.

Comment: Try to clean your whole project, and re-build it again. Probably you will find some errors, and then you should fix them.

Comment: could you elaborate on exactly how to do that? thank you much for your help!

Comment: okay, so I looked closely at my android manifest, and there is an error under application>.InfiniviewerActivity it says it does not exist, could be the core issue? lol

Comment: on menu bars, File Edit etc, choose Project. then choose clean, make sure the "build automatically" is checked. After that, check whether your project built successfully

Comment: find InfiniviewerActivity and add it

Comment: okay, will try that, and let you know if that solves my issue, again thank you very much, you have been a huge help!!!

Comment: real quick, I found my .InfiniviewerActivity where should it go? (based on the Logcat error) or does it matter?

Comment: Is it in your project? you just said it does not exist.

Comment: it does not exist in my project, I located it in a bin folder on my desktop(the folder my developer sent me) for some reason eclipse did not locate/load it, so I do have it, its just not in my project

Comment: im just not sure where it should go in my project build.

Comment: Is it a .class file or jar file? you can add it to your project: right click project -> properties -> java build path -> libraries -> add jar or class

Comment: You'd better find the .java file of InfiniviewerActivity

Comment: yea I found an InfiniviewerActivity .java & .class

Comment: so just move your .java file into your project folder "com/infiniviewer/", and clean whole project again

Comment: Could you email me please? pablo@infinicorpinc.com

Answer (score 0):

Try turning the `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in the manifest file to `false`.
Also, try turning off the webcam emulation in your AVD. (create a fresh AVD without webcam emulation.)

Answer (score 0):

I agree with yushulx this infiniviewer. class file that should be in the src directory or is this some kind of digital microscope? whatever it is infiniviewer is missing.I googled infiniviewer and I still don't know what it is but it's missing